# How to access ChannelFloat32 in python?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rospy, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm on melodic and try to subscribe to a ChannelFloat32 message, but I neither can import the type nor have an Idea how to access that. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349662/how-to-access-channelfloat32-in-python?/) by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @bionade24,

In Python the bindings are:

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import ChannelFloat32
cf_msg = ChannelFloat32()
```

in C++:

```
#include <sensor_msgs/ChannelFloat32.h>
sensor_msgs::ChannelFloat32 cf_msg;
```

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bionade24](https://answers.ros.org/users/41535/bionade24/) on 2020-04-17**:
Thx, I didn't know  that I need .msg additionally in python.